# Accessing command-line arguments in ASM (Win 7)

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm

I'm having trouble accessing the command-line arguments with using ASM.
I've never encountered this problem before, so I'm a bit baffeled...

The assembler I'm using is NASM.

Paste from *nasm -v*:

```
NASM version 2.11 compiled on Dec 31 2013
```

As a linker, I'm using GOLINK as linker.

Relevant info from *golink /h*:

```
GoLink.Exe Version 0.28.0.0 - Copyright Jeremy Gordon 2002/12 - JG@JGnet.co.uk
```

Here is the code I am trying to fix:

```
pop edx ; Return pointer
pop ebx ; ARGC 
pop ecx ; ARGV

push ebx    ; Should push ARGC onto the stack 
push digit  ; db '%d', 10, 0
call printf ; Call printf
```

I'm assembling this using:

```
nasm -f win32 file.asm
```

Linking using:

```
golink /console file.obj msvcrt.dll user32.dll kernel32.dll
```

(I'm using functions from msvcrt.dll, user32.dll and kernel32.dll later in the source)

There are no errors during assembling or linking.

When executing *file.exe helloArg1 helloArg2*, the output is:

```
2130567168
```

Which obviously is not the correct number of arguments...

I highly suspect that I've f-ed up something simple...

I'm currently running a x64 Win 7 (SP 1) box.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your point of entry? If main or WinMain, then command line is a regular C argument - argv or lpCmdLine, respectively.

Comment: Is there any chance the assembler auto generated the stack frame pointer header code, which would be push ebp | mov ebp,esp ? If so, try doing one additional pop instruction (pop ebp) before doing the printf.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: No luck using main or WinMain as the entry point. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: @rcgldr: Thanks for the feedback. I've tried what you described, but sadly, no cigar...

Comment: Then call the `GetCommandLine(A/W)` API.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: That is my backup solution. I'm just more curious as to why this won't work...

Comment: Because Windows does not have an argc or argv.  That is what the C startup code gives you.  Unless you link with a C compiler like gcc, you will have to use `GetCommandLine`

Comment: [This paper](http://in4k.untergrund.net/various%20web%20articles/Creating_Small_Win32_Executables_-_Fast_Builds.htm) claims that the real entry point of Win32 programs doesn't take any arguments (unlike in POSIX). In order to pass the command line to WinMain, the CRT would retrieve it via GetCommandLine().

Answer (score 2):

Use `GetCommandLine()`.

According to [this](http://in4k.untergrund.net/various%20web%20articles/Creating_Small_Win32_Executables_-_Fast_Builds.htm), the real startup function (WinMainCRTSTartup in GUI programs, mainCRTSTartup in console ones) doesn't receive any arguments from the caller. The command line that's eventually passed to main/WinMain is being retrieved via `GetCommandLine()` within the RTL's implementation of xxxCRTStartup.